# What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$$

I suppose that this serie behaves in a similar way that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n}$ , so I have that it converges when $|z| < 1 $.

Could someone explain me if this approach is correct and give me a more rigorous proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can calculate the RC using the $\limsup$ in this case. Indeed your series is $\sum a_n z^n$ where $a_n=1$ if $n=m!$ for some $m$ and $a_n=0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Your "approach" is neither correct nor incorrect, because it is to vague: "this serie behaves in a similar way that" does not mean anything. Besides, it looks that you are asking the solution to an exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|z|<1$, then $|z|^{n!} \leq |z|^n$ so the series converges. If $z=1$, then the series obviously diverges.

So the radius is $1$.